# What's the idiomatic way to join an array into a string?

Tags: arrays, string, crystal-lang

Many languages support constructs like the following (Python, in this case):

```
>>> ["One", "two", "three"].join(" and ")
"One and two and three"
```

In Crystal, what is the idiomatic way to do this?

Comment: Exactly what you just wrote... Join works.

Comment: Oh, duh. Here I go again, not finding the right things in the docs (Google sure didn't help). Part of `Enumerable` and not `Array`, huh.

Comment: ...I just realized it'd actually be `' and '.join(["One", "two", "three"])` in Python, but hey.

Answer (score 3):

Use `#join`, which `Array` inherits from `Enumerable`. The example in the question works just as well in Crystal.